# runtime error 3047 record is too large

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm getting error `3047 in MS Access 2010`. I have a problem in this code When I try running this, I get a peculiar `error:record is too large`

```
Function add()

Dim oDB As DAO.Database

Dim oRst As DAO.Recordset

Dim req As String

Dim req2 As String

Dim req3 As String

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Set oDB = CurrentDb

req = "ALTER TABLE Test ADD COLUMN Zone Text(20);"

req2 = "ALTER TABLE Test DROP COLUMN Zone ;"

req3 = "update Test set Zone= 'zone dense';"

DoCmd.RunSQL (req2)

DoCmd.RunSQL (req)

DoCmd.RunSQL (req3)

End Function
```

Comment: Google result: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080760812.aspx

Comment: How big is `Zone` before you drop it?  How many fields does the table have?

Comment: Which line triggers the error?

Comment: HansUp line: req3 = "update Test set Zone= 'zone dense';"

Comment: D Stanley table contains 2339 record

Comment: The number of *records* in the table is not likely to be the issue, but the number of *fields* might be. Specifically, is it possible that the UPDATE query causes one or more of the records to exceed Access' limit of "4,000 characters in a record (excluding Memo and OLE Object fields) when the UnicodeCompression property of the fields is set to Yes" (ref: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx))?