# Record is too large when I use update query in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to update table by query.

When I use this query I get an error: Record is too large.

```sql
UPDATE 
  tblFact 
  INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tblFact.ProductName = tblProduct.ProductName 
SET 
  tblFact.ProductName_Code = tblProduct.ProductName_Code
```

But when using a query similar to the following, it works:

```sql
UPDATE 
  tblFact 
  INNER JOIN tblRegion ON tblFact.RegionName = tblRegion.RegionName 
SET 
  tblFact.RegionName_Code = tblRegion.RegionName_Code
```

My tblFact table only has 900 records.

I tried separating the table containing about 100 records but still got the above error: Record is too large.

Comment: Why are you saving same data in multiple tables? Review https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/deal-record-large-error-ms-access/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070844/runtime-error-3047-record-is-too-large.

Answer (score 1):

The size of your record is too large. Microsoft tells about the record size:
"Number of characters in a record (excluding Long Text and OLE Object fields) when the UnicodeCompression property of the fields is set to Yes: 4000."
So I guess you hit that limit with at least one record.